# Symfony: set two responses in one call

Tags: php, function, symfony, response

Values from getSettings move to getConfiguration call.
The call is not needed, so I need to remove the method, but its response should be part of configuration service response.

```
    /**
 * @Route("/config", name="app_config")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 */
public function getAppConfigurationAction()
{
    $data = [
        'linkedin' => true,
        'xceedium' => true
    ];


    return $this->success($data);
}

/**
 * @Route("/home", name="home_screen")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 */
public function getHomeScreenApplicationSettings()
{
    $data = [
        'liveFeed' => 'fasle',
        '1 Xceed ' => '20 Euro'
    ];

    return $this->success($data);
}
```

Comment: Merge the content of data in `getHomeScreenApplicationSettings ` with the data of `getAppConfigurationAction ` ?

Comment: I think that is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just merge the content of your `getHomeScreenApplicationSettings` into `getAppConfigurationAction`

Like this :

```
/**
 * @Route("/config", name="app_config")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 */
public function getAppConfigurationAction()
{
    $data = [
        'linkedin' => true,
        'xceedium' => true,
        'liveFeed' => 'fasle',
        '1 Xceed ' => '20 Euro'
    ];


    return $this->success($data);
}
```

You should be carefull if anyone use the deleted route `/home`

I hope I understood your concern, don't hesitate to guide me if not :)

Comment: That's it. I don't know how can't I figure it out. Thnaks a lot!